# Does the electrical conductivity of any conductor decrease extremely due to very high temperature?

Tags: electrical-resistance

I learned that the specific resistance of any conductor increases with increase of temperature. Can a conductor turn into a non conductor due to extreme heat?

Comment: If it becomes a gas that would tend to impact the low voltage conductivity...

Comment: I think you have it backward. Resistance of a conductor increases with increasing temperature.

Comment: Yeah ....sorry.....I meant the opposite.....but....my actual question is Can a conductor lose its conducting ability greatly due to extreme heat?

Comment: @JonCuster But, if it's a [dense plasma](http://fieldp.com/myblog/2012/electrical-conductivity-of-metals-at-high-temperature/) the conductivity goes up. Theoretically.

Comment: @KeithMcClary - sure, but that would take energy input to actually make the plasma  (hence my caveat on low voltage conductivity).

Comment: @KeithMcClary WHAT ABOUT AN EXISTING SOLID METALLIC WIRE?? IS IT POSSIBLE?

Comment: How do you define a "non conductor"? You can find experimental data [here](https://srd.nist.gov/JPCRD/jpcrd258.pdf) and [here](https://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1049&context=ameslab_iscreports).